# How to insert a entity at the end of a table using JPA?

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa

Hello and happy new year for everyone.

I need to insert a record at the end of a table (the table has not set autoincrement) using JPA.

I know I could get the last id (integer) and apply to the entity before insert, but how could that be done? Which way would be most effective?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, while i do not know where the end of a table really is, JPA has a lot of options for plugging in ID generators.

One common option is to use a table of its own, having a counter for each  entity you need an ID for (from http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B32110_01/web.1013/b28221/cmp30cfg001.htm).

```
@Id(generate=TABLE, generator="ADDRESS_TABLE_GENERATOR")
@TableGenerator(
name="ADDRESS_TABLE_GENERATOR", 
    tableName="EMPLOYEE_GENERATOR_TABLE", 
    pkColumnValue="ADDRESS_SEQ"
)
@Column(name="ADDRESS_ID")
public Integer getId() {
    return id;
 }
```

...other "Generator" strategies to be googled...

EDIT

I dare to reference @a_horse_with_no_name as he says he does not know about JPA. If you want to use native mechanisms like sequence (that are not available in every DB) you can declare such a generator in JPA, too.

I do not know what issues he encountered with the table approach - i know large installations running this successfully. But anyway, this depends on a lot of factors besides scalability, for example if you want this to be portable etc. Just lookup the different strategies and select the appropriate.

Comment: having a counter table does not reliably work in a multi-user environment - unless you do exclusive locking on the table. Which in turn makes it slow in environments with a high insert rate. If you only insert a couple of rows an hour there is probably no big performance penalty. But if you want to do hundreds of inserts a minute the locking it *will* be a problem. Btw: sequences are supported by a lot of DBMS such as Oracle, Firebird, PostgreSQL, DB2, H2, Derby, Ingres and Informix. The native solution is **always** faster and more reliable than a counter table.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - how about a shorter name :-)  You're right if you only check out a single number each time - but thats not needed unless you have some special business construct that needs a ascending, non interrupted, unique numbering. Under the hood a sequence is nothing other than a singleton table with atomic, exclusive access. I admit that a layer like JPA will add penality with such constructs . But it still may do some optimization.

Answer (score 3):

There is no such thing as "the end of the table". Rows in a relational table *are not sorted*.

Simply insert your new row. If you need any particular order, you need to apply an `ORDER BY` when selecting the rows from the table.

If you are talking about generating a new ID, then use an Oracle sequence. It guarantees uniqueness.

I would not recommend using a "counter table". 
That solution is either not scalable (if it's correctly implemented) or not safe (if it's scalable).

That's what sequences were created for. I don't know JPA, but if you can't get the ID from a sequence then I suggest you find a better ORM.

Comment: thans for the answer but, when i said "the end of the table" i mean before the last or max id 
i know in a relational table there is not a particular order, problably i didn't explain good

Comment: "Before" does not have a meaning for a primary key as well. Just generate a unique number. Don't be concerned "where" it appears relatively to other primary keys. The actual number of the primary should never have a "meaning". Which is exactly what sequences provide